# SwiftUI Error Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle' when using overlay with shape

Tags: swiftui

Why do I get the error "Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'" in this code? It works in other places.

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: globals.cornerRadius).fill(Color.gray).overlay{
          Spacer()
          Text("Some text")
              .font(Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 17))
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
}.frame(width: .infinity, height: 100)
```

Comment: You mistakenly use curly braces with overlay. Required `.overlay(...)` not `.overlay{...}`

Answer (score 5):

I deduce that your deployment target is iOS 13 or iOS 14 (or something else older than iOS 15).

Your use of `.overlay { ... }` requires [this overload of the `overlay` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(alignment:content:)), which was introduced in iOS 15.

Because your deployment target is something older than iOS 15, the compiler is trying to use [this overload of `.overlay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)) instead, but this overload requires that the overlay content conform to `ShapeStyle`. (This overload was also introduced in iOS 15. Why would Swift prefer it? I don't know! But it's the only one that makes sense for that error message.)

What you really want is [this overload of `.overlay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(_:alignment:)), which allows the overlay content to be any `View`, but doesn't take a function argument. So change `.overlay{ ... }` to `.overlay( ... )`—that is, change the braces to parentheses. You will also need to introduce a `VStack` or other container view. Thus:

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: globals.cornerRadius).fill(Color.gray).overlay(
    VStack {
          Spacer()
          Text("Some text")
              .font(Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 17))
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }
).frame(width: .infinity, height: 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing this compile error in Xcode 14.1RC.

Error:  Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'ShapeStyle'
Submitted Feedback to Apple.

But found that it was a compiler issue... not flagging the "correct" error in the code.

Note: I induced this error changing from a String to Double for the Binding var.  String has isEmpty; but Double does NOT have isEmpty.

```
struct NumberFieldClearButton: ViewModifier {
@Binding var fieldNumber: Double

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .overlay {
            if !fieldNumber.isEmpty {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        fieldNumber = 0.0   // action is to clear value
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .padding(.trailing, 4)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

}

Compiles fine when I remove the IF statement.

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the many unclear error messages in XCode. Though XCode indicates a problem with fill(), the actual problem here seems to be the spacer() in the overlay. The reason is probably that overlay expects a view type. Spacer is not a view type. If you remove Spacer(), the error disappears.

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: globals.cornerRadius).fill(Color.gray).overlay{
          Text("Some text")
              .font(Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 17))
              .foregroundColor(.white)
              .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
}.frame(width: .infinity, height: 100)
```

Comment: Put the Spacer and the Text in a VStack or a Group. The issue is 2 things you have to make them into 1

Comment: @loremipsum No, the issue is the misleading error message. Putting everything in a VStack helps, but the problem is not, as you say, that it is two things that need to be one. If you add no VStack, but a second Text() (or anything else that is a view type) the error message will also go away.

Comment: More likely is that the deployment target is iOS 13 or iOS 14, while `.overlay { ... }` was introduced in iOS 15, so Swift is trying to use a different overload but none of them match the given types.